# Preserving the order in difference between two lists

Tags: python, list, set, set-difference

I have two lists `l` and `l_match`. `l_match` is an empty list.

```
l = ['gtttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacg',
     'tttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacgg',
     'ttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggt',
     'taattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggta',
     'aattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggtat']

l_match = []

print list(set(l) - set(l_match))
```

gives the output

```
['aattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggtat',
 'tttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacgg',
 'ttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggt',
 'taattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggta',
 'gtttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacg']
```

I want the output the same order as the input. i.e. in the above case the output 
should be

```
['gtttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacg',
 'tttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacgg',
 'ttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggt',
 'taattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggta',
 'aattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggtat']
```

Can you suggest edits?

Comment: sets in python do not guarantee order

Comment: `set([])` is the same as `set()` and anything minus the empty set is itself. What are you trying to do?

Comment: So, you want all elements in `l` that aren't in `l_match`?

Answer (score 2):

Just make `l_match` a set:

```
l_match = []

st =  set(l_match)

print([ele for ele in l if ele not in st])
```

If `l` can have dupes use an OrderedDict to get  unique values from `l`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print([ele for ele in OrderedDict.fromkeys(l) if ele not in st])
```

Obviously `l_match` would contain values in the real world or a simple  `l[:] = OrderedDict.fromkeys(l)` would suffice to remove dupes from `l` and keep the order

Comment: But... but... nothing is in `l_match` by definition. What is the point?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, I presumed the OP actually means to use a list with values, I think the order is the point of the question or else it makes zero sense bar removing dupes from l.

Comment: What's gained from making `l_match` a set? What's different here from doing `ele not in l_match`?

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison, in a real world use case where the list actually has values, it is the difference between quadratic and linear

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I hope so, too; I just don't understand then why it is empty in the example code.

Answer (score 2):

This is old af but, in case someone is still wondering about it, a little googling gave me this really simple solution.

```
x = [1, 2, 6, 8, 2, 3]
y = [2, 6]
sorted(set(x) - set(y), key=x.index)
```

output -> [1, 8, 3]

Answer (score 0):

You should look through `l` and include each element therein in your result array only if it's not in `l_match`. This will preserve the order. In python, the statement is a single line:

```
print [entry for entry in l if entry not in l_match]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this: [How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

```
l = ['gtttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacg', 'tttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacgg', 'ttaattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggt', 'taattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggta', 'aattgagttgtcatatgttaataacggtat']
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
print([ x for x in l if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```py
result = list(filter(lambda c: c not in l_match, l))
```