# How to maintain sequence of output list while finding the difference of 2 lists

Tags: python, arraylist

I have to find the difference between a list with another list.

But this process of finding the difference totally randomizes my output every time I run.

Below is my script

```
getALL = ["apple","ball","cat","dog","eagle"]  // initial list


Sourcee = ["eagle", "ball"]
diff = list(set(getALL) - set(Sourcee))
for items in diff:
    print(items)
```

Is there any way to keep the sequence of the the `diff` list same as `getALL`?

I want my output like this:

```
apple
cat
dog
```

Comment: How about a list comprehension: `[i for i in getALL if i not in Source]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preserving the order in difference between two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384312/preserving-the-order-in-difference-between-two-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a list comprehension would work. Optionally converting `Sourcee` to a `set` would make it faster

```
>>> source_set = set(Sourcee)
>>> [e for e in getALL if e not in source_set]
['apple', 'cat', 'dog']
```

Comment: can you please explain this part `[e for e in getALL if e not in source_set]` in simple terms.

Comment: You are just iterating through the list and grabbing its elements `e` for which the condition `e not in source_set` is True. And the condition would be true only when the element `e` is not present in `source_set`

Answer (score 3):

The set operation does not preserve order. However what you can do is to re-build the diff list, by checking what the order was in the original list. This works for any arbitrary order. If the original list contains duplicates this complicates matters.

```
getALL = ["apple","ball","cat","dog","eagle"]  # initial list


Sourcee = ["eagle", "ball"]
diff = list(set(getALL) - set(Sourcee))

original_order_diff = [x for x in getALL if x in diff]

print(original_order_diff)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted`:

```
diff = list(set(getALL) - set(Source))
for items in sorted(diff, key=getALL.index):
    print(items)
```

Even tho:

```
print('\n'.join([i for i in getALL if i not in Source]))
```

And:

```
print(*[i for i in getALL if i not in Source], sep='\n')
```

Would be the shortest solutions.

They all output:

```
apple
cat
dog
```